# Spreading return value of lamda function as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, fluent-ui

I know my title is quite weird. but allow me explain this first.

```js
const alter = (currentFloor: number) => {
        if (overallState.startFloor === '' || overallState.endFloor === '')
            return {}
        if (
            Number(overallState.startFloor) <= currentFloor &&
            Number(overallState.endFloor) >= currentFloor
        ) {
            return { selectedKey: overallState.state }
        }
        return {}
    }

/* ... */

return({
   randomArray.map((e,index)=>(
    <Dropdown 
      placeholder="placeholder"
      options={someoptions}
      {...alter(index)} // how does it works????
    />
))
})
```

I have a function which returns object have prop of fluent UI conditionally.

as you can see, function alter returns object or undefined. but still, it is function.

I never heard about I can spread function itself in curly braces.

These codes work as I intended. but I have no idea how it works.

Can you please ask me what happened in these codes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are fundamendals of how react translates JSX to its own code. Basicaly if you write

```
    <Dropdown 
      placeholder="placeholder"
      options={someoptions}
    />
```

Jsx will be translated to something like

```
React.createElement('Dropdown', {placeholder: "placeholder, options: someOptions})
```

if you use spread syntax like in your code

```
  <Dropdown 
      placeholder="placeholder"
      options={someoptions}
      {...alter(index)} // how does it works????
    />
```

it will be same as

```
React.createElement('Dropdown', {placeholder: "placeholder", options: someOptions, ...alter(index)})
```

and this works, because `alter(index)` function is called, which javascript simply see as given returned object which can be something like `{ selectedKey: overallState.state }` whis is the same as

```
React.createElement('Dropdown', {placeholder: "placeholder", options: someOptions, ...{ selectedKey: overallState.state }})
```

which becomes

```
React.createElement('Dropdown', {placeholder: "placeholder", options: someOptions, selectedKey: overallState.state })
```

and transformed back in JSX

```
 <Dropdown 
      placeholder="placeholder"
      options={someoptions}
      selectedKey={overallState.state}
    />
```

its work just like basic spread syntax of object in function parameters.

Comment: never knew spread operator works like this thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can spread the **return value of a function** in curly braces. **not function itself.**

in this case, your function will run first and return an object.
then that object will spread.

{...alter(index)} -> { ...{ selectedKey: overallState.state } or {}} -> {selectedKey: overallState.state}

Hope you understand.